# Hi! Is there a way to sum (add) rows of a specific column in a dataframe (please see the attached picture)? How does the other columns get affected?

Tags: r

Basically, I wish to sum (add) numeric values in rows (1 and 2; 3 and 4; 12; 13 and 14)  of column 'tdiff' in a dataframe 'taPa'?  I tried taPa [rowSums(1:2, 3:4, 12, 13:14),] but it gives an error: 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please add an example and show expected output for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to add them all together (1-4, 12-14), right?

If that's the case, you could simple use

```
sum(taPa$tdiff[c(1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14)])
```

to get that sum.

Comment: Actually, no. I wish to specifically sum $tdiff values of column $xsampa. So, the rows added would be 1 and 2, only 11, only 12, 13 and 14, and so on. The idea is to add  'p' and 'A' in column $xsampa.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is making no sense. I don't know what you want to do or what the expected result is, nor does the lack of reproducible code help